# Making child div appear causes parent div's height to decrease in Safari only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text input nested in a parent div. When you type in the text input, a "delete text" button appears. When the "delete text" button appears, it causes its parent div "headerSearch" to decrease in height from 71px to 70px ***in Safari only***.

When the "delete text" button is hidden again, the parent div "headerSearch" has it's height go back from 70px to 71px.

Why does displaying the "delete text" button cause the parent div "headerSearch" to change its height in Safari, and how do I prevent it?

Try the code snippet below using Safari where I reproduced the problem.

```js
function deleteSearchBarContents() {
  document.getElementById('searchBox').value = "";
  document.getElementById("searchBox").focus();
  document.getElementById("deleteSearchBarContentsButton").style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("deleteSearchBarContentsButton").addEventListener("click", deleteSearchBarContents);


function showDeleteSearchBarContentsButton() {
  // If value is not empty
  if (document.getElementById("searchBox").value.trim() == "") {
    // Hide the element
    document.getElementById("deleteSearchBarContentsButton").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // Otherwise show it
    document.getElementById("deleteSearchBarContentsButton").style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}
document.getElementById("searchBox").addEventListener("keyup", showDeleteSearchBarContentsButton);
```

```css
.wrapperSearch {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 1111px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.headerSearch {
  background: #3f3f3f;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.entireSearchContainer {
  margin-left: 29.034px;
}

.entireSearchContainer .searchBar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 22.82px;
  height: 46.978px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.entireSearchContainer .searchBar .searchBarInner {
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 47px;
}

.entireSearchContainer .searchBar .searchBox {
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 17.944px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.deleteSearchBarContentsButton {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 46.978px;
  border-radius: 2.618px;
  margin-top: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 0!important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  color: #252525!important;
  display: none;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: 17.944px;
  margin-left: 11.09px;
  color: #888;
  margin-right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.entireSearchContainer .searchBar .searchButton {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 46.978px;
  border-radius: 2.618px;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 46.978px;
  padding-right: 17.944px;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 0!important;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.searchButton img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle!important;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.deleteSearchBarContentsButton {
  display: none;
  padding-right: 0!important;
  width: 17.944px!important;
  margin-left: 11.09px!important;
}

.deleteSearchBarContentsButton img {
  width: 11px!important;
  height: 11px!important;
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperSearch">
  <div class="headerSearch">
    <div class="entireSearchContainer" id="entireSearchContainer">
      <form id="searchForm" name="test" action="https://example.com/" method="GET">
        <div class="searchBar" id="searchBar">
          <div class="searchBarInner">
            <input class="searchBox" id="searchBox">
            <button class="deleteSearchBarContentsButton" id="deleteSearchBarContentsButton" type="button"><img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.f8232e70a6e015e91560068ebde56fb4?rik=LZu9qZIqj6SnLw&riu=http%3a%2f%2fcdn.onlinewebfonts.com%2fsvg%2fimg_376399.png&ehk=mpYEtMisrcWebqodks%2fXno%2fbN9QmLfHuo7tMTVFKGnE%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0"></button>
            <button class="searchButton" type="submit" value="Search"><img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.-9A-FOvJIk9-zy2b0vofXAHaHX?pid=ImgDet&rs=1"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better perhaps to edit the original question rather than delete it and add another.

Comment: A popular OS (windows) does not support Safari (except an likely unsecure/old version - it is no longer updated) and I do not have another environment to test this in that browser ATM, sorry to be a disappointment to you here.

Comment: BTW IF you get this sorted out, add your solution as an answer with the details and accept your own answer - it is fully acceptable to do so here and might help someone else later on.

Comment: Better perhaps to size to a container `width: 80%` or the page base `width: 1.5rem;` rather than all this fixed sizing with `width: 12.222px; height: 47.2323px;` type of styling.  For example you can set the base font to 16px then do `width: 1rem;`  Another suggestion is if you find yourself doing `!important;` likely something is wrong with your CSS stack cascade

Comment: None of this is meant to be critical but more a course of action and suggestion based on experience and a desire to assist you

Comment: Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 0):

```
.entireSearchContainer .searchBar {
  display: block;
}
```

I'm embarrassed this is the solution. Safari didn't like it when the "searchBar" was `display: inline-block;` even though other browsers it was fine.